# Natural Automorphisms of the Path Functor

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

Consider the functor $P: \mathsf{Top \to Set}$ such that $X \to PX$ assigns to every space $X$ the set of continuous functions $f:I\to X$ where $I = [0,1]$, with the Euclidean topology.  It's clear that $P$ is representable as $P\cong \mathsf{Top}(I,\cdot)$.

We can further define a new category $\mathsf{Int}$ consisting of $I$ as the single object and homeomorphisms $f:I\to I$ as the morphisms.  This incidentally turns $\mathsf{Int}$ into a groupoid.

I want to show that natural automorphisms of $P\Longrightarrow P$ correspond bijectively to the category $\mathsf{Int}$.  We can see by the Yoneda lemma that

$$
Nat(P,P) \;\; \cong \;\; Hom\left (\mathsf{Top}(I,\cdot), \mathsf{Top}(I,\cdot) \right ) \;\; \cong \;\; PI \;\; \cong \;\; \mathsf{Top}(I,I).
$$

Since these spaces are isomorphic, if we restrict to the automorphism groupoid $Aut(P)$ can we conclude that

$$
Aut(P) \;\; \cong \;\; \mathsf{Int}?
$$

I'm new to category theory and looking for a bit of a proof-verification in this question.  Is there a better way to phrase this last statement if it were true?  For reference, this is problem 2.2.vii out of Riehl.  Also drawing inspiration from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878280/non-trivial-natural-endomorphisms-on-operatornametop) since this is the problem that precedes it in the book, and is thematically of the same type.

Comment: The bijection in the Yoneda lemma is compatible with composition, so you're just taking the group of units of each side.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.